# Is VIPER Architecting possible using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I was following MVC pattern long term ago , and same is leading to  Massive View Controllers in my project, then changed to VIPER for my last project, In Objective C..

**Is it good to implement the VIPER Architecture in iOS using swift?**

Same for Objective C I found [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/viper/)

Comment: There are a lot of examples to be found online. For example: https://github.com/mutualmobile/VIPER-SWIFT https://www.google.nl/amp/s/cheesecakelabs.com/blog/ios-project-architecture-using-viper/amp/

Comment: VIPER better explained at https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/viper/

Comment: https://medium.com/@Pr0Ger/why-viper-is-a-bad-choice-for-your-next-application-725f4e16fbee you should check this out

Answer (score 1):

Sure,
Viper is a good architecture to reuse components in your app and have a better code coverage. Viper is good to prevent the **M**assive **V**iew **C**ontroller problem in ios apps.

If you want to begin with **viper architecture** you can use [generamba](https://github.com/rambler-digital-solutions/Generamba)